# Get JSON value into a variable

Tags: php, json

how to get the  `["text"]=>
        string(4) "head"` value to the php variable

From the below json

```
var_dump($result)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0M0YR.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$result->tuc[0]->phrase->text;
```

You should really post the var_dump result in your question, and not just link to it, so the q&a remains on SO.

Comment: thank you sir i got the out put really happy :)

Answer (score 1):

To handle json, PHP offers the `json_encode` and `json_decode` functions.

#### Encoding

```
$array = [
    'key' => 'value'
];

$jsonString = json_encode($array);
```

#### Decoding

```
// Decoding will make your json into an object
// If you require json_decode() to output an array,
// you should pass true as a second parameter
$object = json_decode($jsonString);
$array = json_decode($jsonString, true);

// To access a value
echo $json->key;
```

#### Resources

- [json_encode() - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
- [json_decode() - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)